# What do you call a unit of information?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, "The system is too complicated for computers; you couldn't possibly encode every ________ about the system into a program."

I'm looking for a word that's not technical.

Comment: The *fundamental* unit is a ***bit***, but in your context ***datum*** (or perhaps ***metric***) is more suitable.

Comment: I'm looking for something less technical; edited to reflect that

Comment: I think *whatever* word you settle on, your ***about*** isn't likely to sit well with it. But you're inherently in a "technical jargon" context, since you're talking about computers and ***encoding information*** within programs. Ordinary non-computer-literate people don't normally think in terms of encoding discrete "items" of "information" like that.

Comment: I think *bit* is still the best choice. *Every bit of information* is idiomatic also and not necessarily used in technical jargon.

Comment: I agree that *bit* is the best word given what you have presented so far, but it is unclear if *unit of information* is what you really want to express. Program complexity can be attributed to multiple factors, not just the number of instructions required to describe what the program needs to do.

Comment: @jxh it's just an example - the word is what I'm after, not the sentiment of the sentence

Comment: @ermanen if bit is truly idiomatic even among non-techies then that seems to work

Comment: jizzabyte might work here

Comment: "every little bit" forces the idiom but still lets the tech savvy feel content.

Comment: you couldn't possibly encode *everything* about the system into a program - I would say it's non-technical enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the following would fit your example if you prefer not to use "Bit".

"you couldn't possibly encode every ________ of/about the system into a program"

A. [Detail](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/detail)
B. [Aspect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aspect)
C. [Feature](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/feature)

Comment: d. [*facet*](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/facet). [of].  "about" in your example sentence is clunky.

Comment: Its just copied from the OP's example but I agree and have edited.

Answer (score 1):

**iota** to suggest very small. **synapse** to suggest brain-like complexity.

[iota](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/iota):
 an extremely small amount:

> nothing she said seemed to make an iota of difference

[synapse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synapse):
 A junction between two nerve cells, ...a minute gap...

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron#Connectivity):
>   The human brain has a huge number of synapses. Each of the 1011 (one
>   hundred billion) neurons has on average 7,000 synaptic connections to other
>   neurons. It has been estimated that the brain of a three-year-old child has
>   about 1015 synapses (1 quadrillion).